# Odoo _inherit = 'ir.attachment' access rights

Tags: python, odoo

When I created a class in Odoo I used **_name = '...'** and **_inherit = ['mail.thread', 'mail.activity.mixin', 'ir.attachment']**.
With it I also created a customized view for my new module Documents. Unfortunately I only have access to the documents with admin rights. If I give a user the following rights,
only then he / she has access to the documents.
**Administration: Settings**

Which rights and where would I have to set in order to give all users the right to read and create documents in my new module with inherited "ir.attachment"?

Comment: I'm just curious, why do you want to inherit from `ir.attachment`?

Comment: it is faster to implement and you don't need to create fields and through the inherit you have everything ready. Then I take over the ir.attachment - view and adapt it.

Creating a new model that inherits "ir.attachment". Any access control  rules and security rules applied to this new model will be isolated and will not effect the behavior of attachments in other modules.

Comment: But what is so special in `ir.attachment`? The view is probably one of the ugliest in all Odoo, because in the end the attachment model is more a technical one and later specially used by the client with all its extra widgets for it.

Comment: There is nothing special. I don't know my way around. I am new in creating modules. Thanks for the quick answer.

Comment: Yeah but what is your intention or your reason on inherting it? I'm just asking because my experience and my gut feeling tell me there will be another way more simple solution to your requirements ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Its under the Technical Settings, Record Rules. Just search the model that you have problems with.

Comment: Thank you, I will have a look.